Why does the relation between Jake and the gunslinger change during book 1?
I've recently finished reading The Gunslinger, book 1 in Stephen King's Dark Tower series. What confused me is why the relation between Jake and Roland changed, with both of them apparently foreseeing how it would end later on in the story.

When they first meet, despite a lack of trust that's natural when you suddenly run across a total stranger in an empty desert, they bond fairly quickly and begin to work together.

They travel together for perhaps more than half of the book, with Roland taking care of Jake and Jake valiantly surviving the tough conditions of the desert and mountains. The word "love" is used in Roland's inner monologue to describe his feelings towards the boy.

At some point, Jake begins to mistrust Roland, assuming (for some reason) that the gunslinger will abandon or even kill him at some later stage. Roland says little aloud, but internally he also recognises (for some reason) that he will end up betraying Jake, and hates himself for acting to keep the boy's trust while knowing it's undeserved.

Towards the end of the book,

 Jake apparently dies, falling from the rails suspended over a great height.

Oddly, this moment goes almost unremarked, with Roland apparently feeling little emotion except a momentary acknowledgement that the boy's face will haunt him in the future. It's unclear if Roland could have prevented it from happening (i.e. he essentially betrayed Jake) or if it was an accident that had nothing to do with Roland's actions.


I'm assuming (and this earlier Q&A confirms it) that we haven't seen the last of Jake, and he'll reappear somehow in later books of the series. My question is not about what will happen later (and therefore not a duplicate of the linked post) but, within the timeline of the first book, why Roland and Jake both foresaw the former betraying the latter. Why did their relation change, apparently predicting (correctly, as it turned out) that the gunslinger would abandon his travelling companion somewhere along their journey? What happened to convince Jake that his guardian would let him down, and what happened to make Roland self-flagellatingly resigned to losing his friend?

It's been quite a while since I read it, so I won't attempt an answer (yet). However, I remember it definitely being Roland's fault by mere inaction to rescue Jake in favour of pursuing the tower. So it's clear to both of them that he sacrificed the boy for his quest. As to them kind of predicting it, I suppose it comes down to pretty much that, a premonition of the sacrifice Roland will have (and is willing) to make, a foreshadowing manifesting in their conciousness. A lot of stuff like this can usually be prescribed to the mystical concept of ka (or the metaphysics for "coincidence" ;-)).
